# Json result parse from ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am new to javascript and an ajax function is returning me

```
{ _id: 5964ff51b3ac0b201822c357,
  userName: 'saurabhjj',
  friendName: 'friend1' }
```

This data is returned from an ajax call, I want to extract this data

Below is my code

```
console.log(data);
var result = JSON.stringify(data);

        if(result){
            console.log(" result :::; " + result.friendName);
            console.log(" result :::; " + result['friendName']);
        }

        if(data){
            console.log(" data :::; " + data.friendName);
            console.log(" data :::; " + data['friendName']);
        }
```

The output I get is

```
result :::; undefined
 result :::; undefined
 data :::; undefined
 data :::; undefined
```

Please assist

Comment: `var result = JSON.stringify(data);` you have turned your object into a string, which has no properties "friendName" or "userName"

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: I have updated my code, please find all the tried ways

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise we cannot help you. As it is, it is unclear what the exact value of `data` is.

Comment: data is printing the above value, to me it does not seem as if it is a JSON, I am trying to extract the requisite value.

Comment: If this really is the exact output you see in the console, then you have a string. This is not JSON, so you cannot parse it as JSON. There is no simple solution to that problem. The ideal solution would be to fix whatever generates the string to produce JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If the `data` is already an object:

```
data.friendName
```

Otherwise use `parse` to convert it:

```
result = JSON.parse(data);
result.friendName;
```

Comment: You got it the wrong way round. If it is JSON it needs to be parsed.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: :(( my bad there guys :((

Comment: See me second comment. JavaScript objects are not JSON.

Comment: JSON is a representation.  There is no such thing as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you stringify it? Try data.friendName without using JSON.stringify